# Page not Found (404) in django

Tags: python, django

Am using django I got this error  Page not Found (404) Request Method: GET Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/  Using the URLconf defined in VibezT.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order

1. music/
2. admin/

The empty path didn't match any of these.

VibezT\urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin

from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns =[

    path('music/', include('music.urls')),

    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

]
```

For music URLs I have this code

music\urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views  

urlpattern = [

    path(r'^$',/  views.index, name='index')

]
```

For views i have this code

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):

    return HttpResponse("Hello World")
```

Comment: Do you have a stray `/` here: `path(r'^$',/  views.index, name='index')`?

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined a URL for `/` in your code. Your code is defined for `music/`

You need to go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/music/ to find your view.

Also, I do not know why you are structuring your URL like this if you are using path. `path(r'^$',/  views.index, name='index')`

Just replace that with this:

`path('', views.index, name='index'),`

in your music\urls.py

Comment: I went to http://127.0.0.1:8000/music/ and these error show up using the URLconf defined in VibezT.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order: 1. music/^$ [name='index']  2. admin/          the current path, music/, didn't match any of these

Comment: I also do not know why you are structuring your thing like this ` "    path(r'^$',/  views.index, name='index')
"`

Comment: Am actually following a tutorial video